# Minecraft 1.12 testfor command conversion to 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was using the `/testfor` command to have a command block open an iron door if there was a feather (or other item) in a nearby item frame. 1.13 doesn't seem to recognize it. Anybody know how this works in 1.13?

```
testfor @e[type=Item_Frame,r=5] {Item:{id:"minecraft:feather"}}
```

Comment: Well, what does the error message tell you?

Answer (score 1):

**The */testfor* command became obsolete in Minecraft 1.13, and has been replaced by the */execute* command**<sup>*</sup>.

Quoting user RecycledCap:

> *nbt data* is a selector in the new update so you can do for example
>   
> `execute at @e[nbt={<nbt>}]`
>
> You can do this to fix your problem:
>
> `/execute if entity @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"<item>":}}] run <command>`
>
> It will do the same as typing `/testfor @e {SelectedItem:{id:"<item>"}}`
>   and then putting a comparator to the command block with the command,
>   and then running the command which you wanna run.

In your case, 
`testfor @e[type=Item_Frame,r=5] {Item:{id:"minecraft:feather"}}` 
becomes something like 
`/execute if entity @e[type=Item_Frame,r=5;nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:feather":}}] run <command>`.

<sup>* Source is [this thread on Minecraftforum.net](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2887424-solved-whats-the-1-13-equivalent-of-testfor)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Joachim is close but the command will not succeed.

The testfor command has been removed and was replaced with the if option in the execute command.

The [execute command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) equivalent:

```
execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,distance=..5,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:feather"}}] run <chained command>
```

Replace `chained command` with whatever command you want to execute if the conditions are true.

Comment: And if I just want it to activate the comparator next to it, what would I put for run?

Comment: After messing around for a while longer, I'm finding the problem is the distance command. Each time I add a distance, the command stops working altogether. I'm not getting any error messages.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the comparator?  There is probably a better way.  Generally command block contraptions are best with no redstone involved.   How are you adding distance?  You might update your question to include the details on what you are trying to accomplish so that possible better solutions could be recommended.